# Uploading an extension on Magento Marketplace

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, marketplace

What do I need to know to upload a theme or extension on the Magento Marketplace?

Comment: http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/extensions/extension-submit-business-review.html

Comment: Ask this question on Community  or meta

Comment: It's not the goal of the Meta. https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento currently invests in ensuring high extension quality by strictly adhering to the  following checks for every new extension submission request:

**Business review:** Ensures that each extension solves a business problem and delivers rich and unique functionality.

**Tech review:** Detects the presence of viruses, malware, and any indications of plagiarism. Ensures that the package meets Composer packaging and format requirements along with all coding standards.

**Marketing review:** Verifies that all documentation and appropriate information is provided for each extension.

[image: Magento Marketplace]

References:

https://magento.com/blog/technical/improvements-magento%E2%80%99s-extension-quality-program
http://www.magenerds.com/2016/07/10/setting-up-magento-2-on-docker/
http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/extensions/extension-quality-program.html
http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/getting-started-seller.html