# Magento Marketplace Extensions VS Other Extensions

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, marketplace

A member of the Magento Team told me to prefer to use the Marketplace Extensions ([I know about the audit process](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/173930/16416)) than the other third-party extensions (e.g. from Github or aleatory module store).

**Can you explain me listing the pros vs cons of each one using a technical overview?**

Magento Marketplace Extensions X Other Extensions

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If normal extension uploading on Marketplace there are many septs which is marked Magento 2 extension better then another extension.

1. Business Review
2. Technical Review
3. Marketing Review
4. QA Review

> **Magento Marketplace Extensions**

1. Dependency Check

   a) Global ($_GET, $_FILE) variable do not use.

   b) Do not use Core extension code.

   c) Do not use redeclaration of code (class use)
2. composer.json file is proper because 
   it is checked by Marketplace Team.
3. If use Magento market place extension Then no issue with extension because it is Check with the Magento marketplace team.
4. From Magento 2 admin panel, we are directly installing or upgrade Magento marketplace extension.

> **Other Extensions**

1. Not check any Dependency.
2. May be issue in composer.json , No one check.
3. Normal developer not check dependency, If extension working in 2.0.x, It may be possible which is not working in Magento version 2.1.x.
4. Which is not possible if we are use other extension.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the extensions in the marketplace are verified by code sniffer tool and compiled by the vendor before they are released to market place, where as in other sources we don't exactly know whether the code is verified or not which might cause problems the entire project.